# how passing char* to a function works?

Tags: c, pointers

I have tried this code!I can't understand how it works.

```
     int main()
     {
         char *s1;
         s1=malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
         strcpy(s1,"main");
         printf("%s\n",s1);
         func(s1);
         printf("After call %s\n",s1);
         return 0;
      }
      void func(char *s2)
      {
         //free(s2);<--------------(this is what I'm talking about)
         s2=malloc(sizeof(char)*25);
         strcpy(s2,"func");
         printf("fun---%s\n",s2);
      }
```

Output:

```
     main
     fun---func
     After call main
```

But if in func() I add the commented line output is

Outout:

```
     main
     fun---func 
     After call main
```

I want to know how the whole thing works. I mean `s1` is `char*`. After allocating it points to a chunk of memory. In C everything is pass by value. So when we pass it there will another variable created in the local scope of (stack) `main` that holds the address of the chunked memory (i.e., `s1` contains this same value).

- Now if we allocate then there is no chance of getting the reflection of change in `s1` in `main()`. As `s1` is never changed.
- But if we free it then I should get a garbage value in main in `printf()` after calling the function `func()`.

Is this the correct idea? If not please clear the concept. In Windows it gave the result as I have told you. But in Linux it was somehow reflecting the change.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5):

You're (mostly) correct.

Freeing `s2` (and hence `s1`) in the function then using `s1` on return to `main()` is what's known as undefined behaviour.

You shouldn't do it because the standard mandates that pretty much *anything* is allowed to happen and, here's the rub, that "anything" includes the possibility that it will work.

*Why* it's working is almost certainly because no-one else has allocated that memory block again and overwritten the data in it, so it still contains what was originally in there.

If, in your `main()` between the call to `func()` and the printing of `s1`, you inserted:

```
char *s3 = malloc(10000);
strcpy (s3, "Yoohoo, I'v changed");
```

then you may *well* find that printing `s1` will give you a different result.

Or, since it's UB, maybe not :-)

It's advisable to avoid undefined behaviour even if it seems to work. Changing your compiler, or compiler flags, or order of the code, or even compiling on a blue moon, may change how your code works in unexpected ways.

---

If you want to pass back a pointer allocated in a function (other than by just using `return`), you can use double indirection:

```
void allocStr (char **pStr) {
    free (*pStr);
    *pStr = malloc (1000);
}
:
char *xyzzy = NULL;
allocStr (&xyzzy);
```

This is how you do pass-by-reference in C.

Comment: Thanks! Now if I do not add the line free() in func and allocate there is also memory leak.But there is no way I can allocate by passing only a char* to a function and allocate memory that reflects the change in the calling function isn't it?

Comment: @amalsom You would have to pass a pointer to the pointer which you want to change for that, like with any other value you want to change in a function.

Comment: @amalsom. to allocate memory and pass it back, you use _double_ indirection, I'll update the answer.

Comment: "All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection" (David Wheeler)

Comment: @paxdiablo: Yeah that's what I am asking that we can't allocate it by passing a char* variables content to another function.In my linux m/c though it worked suprisingly.But according to my example if I change a char of string pointed by s1 like --- in func() s2[0]='m' then it will be reflected.Isn't it?Pleae check if this is correct.

Comment: @amalsom, yes. what you need to remember is that `s2[0]` _isn't_ changing the value of `s2` itself, it's changing the memory that `s2` _points to._ The rule is: if you want to change something passed in, you need a pointer to it,

Answer (score 3):

(This doesn't answer your question, but it's to much to put in a comment.)

To make it work without [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) you need to pass the pointer *by reference* (or rather, since it's not possible in C you have to emulate pass by reference semantics). This can be done by passing a pointer to the pointer, then you can change it in the function.

Something like

```
void func(char **s2);  // Pointer to pointer

int main(void)
{
    char *s1 = malloc(20);  // No need for `sizeof` as `sizeof(char)` is always 1
    strcpy(s1, "main");
    func(&s1);  // Note use of `&` address-of operator
}

void func(char **s2)
{
    free(*s2);  // Note use of dereference operator `*`
    *s2 = malloc(20);
    strcpy(*s2, "func");
}
```

Comment: @Joachim.Thanks.Yeah! you are using the char** that stores the address of the variable s1.So any change made through this will be reflected as it is occurring with the actual variable though it address is contained by a temporary variable which will not be there after the end of func().thanks.Please tell me if my idea is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The whole thing works exactly as you said. The reason you didn't get garbage on the second run when dereferencing a stale pointer (s2 pointing to freed memory) is, that the system just hadn't reused the memory yet.

Comment: Thanks ..I think that's what happened when I have run it in my linux m/c yesterday.